# How to make electron app supports CLI, embed oclif project?

Tags: electron, command-line-interface, oclif

I built an CLI app using oclif, and is planning to support desktop app using electron.
I am wondering if it's possible to let electron supports CLI without opening a window.

It would be the best if I can reuse existing oclif code in the electron project.

Comment: Have you found any answer or workarounds about this ?